# How to change menu icon size in Codename One Toolbar?

Tags: codenameone

How can I change the size of the OverflowMenu(3 vertical dots) icon?

I have tried menuImageSize constant and it affected only the SideMenu (3 vertical line) icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the theme constant `overflowImageSize` similarly to `menuImageSize`.