# How to change right side menu icon size in cn1?

Tags: codenameone

I couldn't figure out how to customize it(change the size, color...) of the menu icon (3 horizontal lines). It's small, I need to increase the size.

I saw this question [How to change menu icon size in Codename One Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428512/how-to-change-menu-icon-size-in-codename-one-toolbar) but it's too old and I didn't find the 'menuImageSize' theme constant, although it appears in the documentation.

[menuImageSize not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4loz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should still work fine despite the age. You can edit the value in the combo box. Notice we recommend working with CSS nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for helping, it worked. Then I will use the css.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Style to customize it. See dashboard's hamburger icon of this app [FeaturesCN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomuhtech.cn.features).

And these implementations; [hamburger command](https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/FeaturesCN1-Ant/blob/master/src/com/zomuhtech/cn/features/Dashboard.java#L110-L118) and [Styling](https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/FeaturesCN1-Ant/blob/c08e38e265a8091d2bbbe4d2db86392ff031d308/src/com/zomuhtech/cn/features/procs/Proc.java#L367-L388)

Since your hamburger is on the right use

```
tb.addCommandToRightBar(menuCmd);
```

instead of

```
tb.addCommandToLeftBar(menuCmd);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll check the app.