# Hard to click button and menu on iphone 12. How do I solve this issue?

Tags: codenameone

My app(developed by cn1) has a menu and a command on the toolbar. It works fine in Android but hard to click through the menu and command on iPhone(X, 12...) with the notch.

Please see the image marked with the red circles.

How do I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: I suggest increasing the padding slightly. iOS grabs touch events from the top bar and might "steal" these taps.

Comment: Would you let me know which component's padding to increase? Toolbar or others?

Comment: Use the component inspector to experiment but generally I would try `TitleCommand` & `MenuButton`.

Comment: You can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76332447/how-to-change-right-side-menu-icon-size-in-cn1/76338238#76338238)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by getToolbar().setUIID().